# How to select the html attribute inside a selenium object

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I am learning web scraping using selenium and I've come into an issue when trying to select an attribute inside of a selenium object.  I can get the broader data if I just print elems.text inside the loop (this outputs the whole paragraph for each listing) however when I try to access the xpath of the h2 title tag of all the listings inside this broader element, it only appends the first listing to the titles array, whereas I want all of them. I checked the XPATH and they are the same for each listing. How can I get all of the listings instead of just the first one?

```
titles = []
driver.get("https://www.sellmytimesharenow.com/timeshare/All+Timeshare/vacation/buy-timeshare/")

results = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "results-list")

for elems in results:
    print(elems.text) #this prints out full description paragraphs
    elem_title = elems.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search-page"]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/a[1]/div/div[1]/div/h2')
    titles.append(elem_title.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't limited to accessing the elements by XPATH only, then here is my solution:

```
results = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "result-box")
for elems in results:
    titles.append(elems.text.split("\n")[0])
```

When you try getting the listings, you use `find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "results-list")`, but on the website, there is only one element with the class name `"results-list"`. This aggregates all the text in this div into one long string and therefore you can't get the heading.

However, there are multiple elements with the class name `"result-box"`, so `find_elements` will store each as its own item in `"results"`. Because the title of each listing is on the first line, you can split the text of each element by the newline.

Comment: Ahh I didn't realize that was only one div, I just assumed it held all of the results. Thank you!